# Get all descendants of the given parent

Tags: java, algorithm

Hello, I have a List of Category:

```
public class Category{
   private Integer id;
   private Integer parentId;
}
```

How can I get a List of all descendants/children of the given parent?

For example:

```
  1 : 2
  1 : 3
  2 : 4
```

And for 1 I will get 2,3,4

Comment: Have you tried some coding yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: Please show some code... How does your `Category` class look like?

Comment: If a parent has children, iterate over them and call the method recursivly, checking then again if the have children and so on. If they don't then just return the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple (possibly inefficient) method which uses a recursive attempt

```
public List<Integer> getChildrenIds(Integer parentId, List<Category> categories){
    Set<Integer> knownParents = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Category category : categories){
        // if category has the parent we're looking for
        if(category.parentId.equals(parentId)){
            // then add it to our result
            result.add(category.id);
            // this check is used to get all the children recursivly
            // but should be done only once, which is why we are using an intermediate set
            if(!knownParents.contains(category.id)){
                knownParents.add(category.id);
                result.addAll(getChildrenIds(category.id, categories));
            }            
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
List<Integer> childrenIds = getChildrenIds(1, categories);
```

## Note

This breaks with a `StackOverflowError` when you have inconsistent data.

E.g. when having 2 Categories, referencing each other:

```
Category(id: 1, parentId: 2)
Category(id: 2, parentId: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list of all categories and check for *direct* children of a given id, see this example:

```
public class MainCategoryChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create some categories and put them in a List
        List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

        Category one = new Category(1, 0);  // the root category has parent id = 0
        categories.add(one);
        Category two = new Category(2, 1);
        categories.add(two);
        Category three = new Category(3, 1);
        categories.add(three);
        Category four = new Category(4, 2);
        categories.add(four);

        printSubCategories(1, categories);
    }

    public static void printSubCategories(int parentId, List<Category> categories) {
        for (Category c : categories) {
            if (c.getParentId() == parentId) {
                System.out.println(parentId + " : " + c.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```